# If three input are filled and two specific ones are equal it changes button style; it works, unless value of 'not equal' input is not deleted

Tags: javascript, html, validation, if-statement, conditional-statements

```js
function validatePW()
{
 var r_pw=document.getElementById('register_password').value;
 var r_cpw=document.getElementById('register_confirmpw').value;
 var r_button=document.getElementById('register_button');
 var r_user=document.getElementById('register_username').value;

 if(r_cpw)
 {
  if (r_pw == r_cpw)
  {
   document.getElementById('message_alert').innerHTML='';
   if(r_user)
   {
    r_button.disabled = false;
    r_button.style.opacity = 1;
   }
  }else{
   document.getElementById('message_alert').innerHTML='doesnt match';
   r_button.disabled = true;
   r_button.style.opacity = 0.5;
  }
 }
}

document.getElementById('register_username').onkeyup = function()
{
 validatePW();
}
document.getElementById('register_confirmpw').onkeyup = function()
{
 validatePW();
}
document.getElementById('register_password').onkeyup = function()
{
 validatePW();
}
```

```css
.headline
{
 padding-bottom:1px;
 margin-bottom:25px;
 text-align:center;
 box-shadow:0 1px 0 #bbbbbb;
}
.content
{
 display:inline-block;
 padding:10px 30px 30px 30px;
 margin:10px 50px;
 background:#eeeeee;
 border-radius:3px;
 border:1px solid #bbbbbb;
}
.center
{
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 text-align:center;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateY(-50%);
}
h1
{
 display:inline-block;
 font-weight:400;
}
.sign_up_input
{
 float:left;
 margin-left:-2px;
}
.sign_up_input input
{
 line-height:24px;
 border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
 border:1px solid #bbbbbb;
}
.sign_up_icon
{
 float:left;
 display:inline-block;
}
.sign_up_icon div
{
 padding:1px 9px 0 9px;
 background:#ddd;
 border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;
 border:1px solid #bbbbbb;
 height:25px;
 box-shadow:inset -2px -3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.025);
}
#register_button
{
 width:218px;
 padding:1px 0;
 font-size:18px;
 background:#dddddd;
 border-radius:3px;
 border:1px solid #bbbbbb;
 opacity:0.5;
}
#register_button:active
{
 box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
#message_alert
{
 float:left;
 margin-top:3px;
 font-size:12px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="center">
   <div>
                <div class="content">
     <div class="headline"><h1>REGISTER</h1></div>
     <div class="sign_up_icon"><div><img src="" style="height:22px; margin:1px 2px;"/></div></div>
     <div class="sign_up_input"><input type='text' name='register_username' id='register_username' maxlength="64"/></div><br><br>
     <div class="sign_up_icon"><div><img src="" style="height:26px; margin-top:-1px;"/></div></div>
     <div class="sign_up_input"><input type="password" name="register_password" id="register_password" maxlength="64"/></div><br><br>
     <div class="sign_up_icon"><div style="padding:1px 2px 0 9px;"><img src="" style="height:26px; margin-top:-1px;"/><span style="display:inline-block; font-size:13px; line-height:32px; vertical-align:top; margin-left:-3px">✔</span></div></div>
     <div class="sign_up_input"><input type="password" name="register_confirmpw" id="register_confirmpw" maxlength="64"/></div><br><br>
     <span id="message_alert"></span><br><br>
     <a href="#"><input id="register_button" type="button" value="Register" onclick="return regformhash(this.form, this.form.username, this.form.email, this.form.password, this.form.confirmpwd); disabled"/></a>
    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The problem is here:

```
if(r_user)
{
    r_button.disabled = false;
    r_button.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

If you type into the inputs normally it works perfectly, unless you delete the value of the first input. Then, the register-button doesn't hide as it should. Even if there is no value in the first input. As you change a value in the lower inputs again it works fine.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if(r_cpw && (r_pw == r_cpw) && r_user) {
    enable your submit here
}
else {
    disable your submit here
}
```

Or think about the place of your `else` statement, there's one brace closed before it that may be your problem (your code never tells what to do when your last `if` test is evaluated falsy...)

Comment: thanks fpierrat :)
just added else statement and it works fine for me now c: